# What really happens when a UIView becomes hidden?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiwindow, messageui

This may sound like a weird question, but what exactly happens when it becomes hidden. It would be great to see the UIView source code, but that isn't going to happen.

Here why I'm wondering:
I'm trying to add a UIWindow (a transparent one with userinteractionenabled set to NO) above my application to tint the screen. It works perfectly fine until the user tries to share by SMS using Apples MessageUI.framework. When this happens and the MFMessageComposeViewController or MFMailComposeViewController appears, these view controllers won't receive user input. I've tried tons of thing and the only things that worked, allowing the user to interact with the views, was setting the UIWindow (the one I added) to either an alpha of 0 or set hidden to YES. I want to replicate this without hiding the view, which is why I want to know exactly what happens when the UIWindow (which is a subclass of UIView) is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is usually only one window in iOS apps. You're better off using just a `UIView` for this task instead of a `UIWindow`. `UIWindow` adds some view hierarchy and event management capabilities to the `UIView` class. This functionality is interfering with the expected behavior in your app. I think it will just work if you change the class of this view to `UIView` instead of `UIWindow`.

Comment: I switched to using a UIWindow after a UIView produced the same unwanted result.

Comment: Are you using presentModalViewController:animated: to show the composing view controllers?